# Error when trying to add multiple rows of data to table using SQL Query

Tags: sql, insert

I'm trying to insert multiple lines of data into a table that I created using SQL. Adding just one line into the table everything works fine. Whenever I put the comma after the first line in order to add more data that's when I get the error message "Incorrect syntax near ','." which is in reference to the first comma after the first line of data.

Copy of code:

```
CREATE TABLE Workers (
    PersonID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Age int NOT NULL,
    Specialty nvarchar(50)
)


INSERT INTO Workers (FirstName, LastName, Age, Specialty)
    VALUES ('Marvin','Smith',30,'Bossman'),
           ('Jon','Reid',26,'Mentor'),
           ('Dexter','Akers',22,'New Guy'),
           ('John','Cena',26,'Hiding');
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it was a database that I created is that what you mean?

Comment: . . No.  What is the name of the database software.  Your code looks like SQL Server code and your statements work in that database:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bbb45fda01f360724066c793dcf4fe61.

Comment: @GordonLinoff oh I am using SSMS 18